# Sublime to use Sass instead of CSS syntax for SCSS files?

Tags: sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 keeps opening SCSS files with CSS syntax instead of Sass.  They use different syntax color highlights, so I'd like to have Sublime Text default to Sass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open an SCSS file in Sublime Text.

Click View->Syntax->Open all with current extension as...->CSS

These settings get stored in the language specific files under

Windows :

> %userdir%\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\LANGUAGE.sublime-settings

Linux :

> ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/LANGUAGE.sublime-settings

So in your case you'd want to have this inside CSS.sublime-settings

```
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "scss"
    ]
}
```

I keep that directory in a git repo to make settings migration across machines easier.

Comment: You're a life saver!  Or at least a huge time saver. :-)

Comment: added some more info so you can understand how/where sublime stores this kind of information

Answer (score 0):

Open an SCSS file, then go to **`View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> Sass`**. This will change the syntax to Sass, and all future `.scss` files will be opened with the Sass syntax.